# How to resize image to put into tf.train.Example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an image (JPEG or PNG) as a byte buffer (read from the internet), and this is the way I was putting it in a `tf.train.Example` before:

```
record = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_bytes)
    # there are more features but they're not relevant
}))
```

However, for my usecase, the images are too big, so I'd like to resize them either before I put them in the `tf.train.Example` or just after (whichever is easiest).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
# predeclared
# - image_bytes
# - image_format
# - height
# - width

# resize image
if image_format == b'jpeg':
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_bytes, None, tf.float32)
elif image_format == b'png':
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image_bytes, None, tf.float32)

image = tf.image.resize_images(image, (int(height), int(width)))

image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)
record = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(tf.image.encode_jpeg(image))
    # there are more features but they're not relevant
}))
```

I suspect this is valid right up until I actually try to put it in the `tf.train.Example`, at which point it tells me `TypeError: <tf.Tensor 'EncodeJpeg:0' shape=() dtype=string> has type Tensor, but expected one of: bytes`. I've tried figuring out how to get the `Tensor` into a `BytesList` or something like it, but I haven't been able to find any documentation for this. I suspect there may be a better way to approach the entire process however.

How can I do this the right way?

Comment: You store images as byte arrays?

Comment: They come from the internet as byte arrays. Not really TF related.

Comment: Error states that this tensor shoud be evaluated. Have you tried using numpy or cv2 for encoding/decoding?

Comment: No. I don't really know how to do that. How does it state that this tensor should be evaluated? It seems to me like it's just saying it wants to be converted to bytes, which I wouldn't call "evaluation". It's just data, right?

Comment: tf.image.encode_jpeg returns tensor, and in order to get it content it should be ran inside session

Comment: Oh... do Tensors represent lazy work? I thought they were just arrays with data in them already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize prior to encoding.

```
def int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

Convert from string and resize

```
image = numpy.fromstring(byte_arr).reshape((height, width, channels))
image_raw = image.tostring()
```

Then serialize as tfrecords file

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfr_name)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature{'height':int64_feature(height),
                                                              'width': int64_feature(width),
                                                              'channels': int64_feature(channels),
                                                              'image_raw': bytes_feature(image_raw),

writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I ended up using cv2, but I think it's the same idea. I thought I could use tensorflow for this, but it seems like it's not worth it. This part isn't performance critical.